# Python - Printing individual cells from an Excel spreadsheet in CSV format

Tags: python, excel, csv

I have an excel spreadsheet saved as a CSV file, but cannot find a way to call individual values from cells into Python using the CSV module. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Do you have any code we could look at?  The csv module has a couple of different ways to *store* the data it reads from a csv file.

Comment: I am literally just trying to print a value from inside a cell in an excel spreadsheet, but as I only have the CSV module installed, have to have it saves as a CSV file

Comment: Have you looked at the examples in the documentation for the csv module?

Comment: Would you show us the code you are using?

Answer (score 1):

There is also a Python library capable of reading xls data. Have a look at [`python-xlrd`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd).

For writing xls data, you can use [`python-xlwt`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlwt).

Answer (score 1):

The csv module provide readers that iterate over the rows of a csv file - the *rows* are lists of strings.  One way to get access to individual *cells* would be to:

Read the entire file in as a list of lists

```
import csv
with open('test.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    the_whole_file = list(reader)
```

Then access the individual cells by indexing into `the_whole_file`.  The first index is the row and the second index is the column - both are zero based. To access the cell at the second row, fourth column:

```
row = 1
column = 3
cell_R1_C3 = the_whole_file[row][column]

print cell_R1_C3
```

Comment: This has done the job, thanks very much and sorry for being so vague.

Comment: This may not be an optimal solution for your task.  In the future if you can show us code examples and expected results and explain why it doesn't do what you want, *we* might see a better solution than you have thought of.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the excel file as a CSV, you can use [csv.reader](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader)

```
import csv
myFilePath = "/Path/To/Your/File"
with open(myFilePath,'rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader( csvfile, delimiter=',' )
    for row in reader:
        # 'row' has all the cells (thanks to wwii for the fix!). Get the first 4 columns
        a, b, c, d = row[:4]
```

Comment: ```row``` will be a list of strings - lists do not have a split() method.  The individual cells can be accessed by indexing into ```row```, like ```row[1]``` or the row can be unpacked - ```a, b, c, d = row``` (assuming 4 columns).

Comment: So do I use this code but with the number column I would like to call following "row". e.g. "cell = row[17].split(',')?

Comment: No, you can just use `cell17 = row[17]`

Comment: Thanks for the help so far, but still using all of this it's not singling out the individual cells and I'm still getting a lot of numbers. Is there something fundamentally wrong I'm doing?

Comment: The csv module module lets you read the data a row at a time.  To get the data for a single cell you need to read the row that contains that cell then access the cell's data within that row. The ```xlrd``` module can read an xls file and may have the funtionality you are looking for.